# SELECT MAX for multiple

Tags: sql, select, max

I'd like to find the userid and max transcript record for two (or more) classes in one query but i am only getting one max record for the two, i.e. if i user took both classes i'm on only getting the max record for the last class he took, not the max record of both classes.

i'd like to get the max record for both classes.
This is what i've got:

```
select userid, max(transcriptid)
from chris_dwh.ekp_transcript_v t
where t.learningid in ('EKP000000708', 'EKP000000523')
```

my result is one userid and one transcriptid when i'd like to see something like

```
userA    EKP009037723
userA    EKP009036301
userB    EKP009057809
userB    EKP008479198
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data too, with the matching expected result.

Comment: You have an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.  That is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Not _semantically_ correct.

Comment: `t` is a poor table alias. Chose something that makes sense, like `e`, `et` or `ekpt` for ekp_transcript_v.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to add `learningid` to your `group by`?

```
select t.userid, max(t.transcriptid)
from chris_dwh.ekp_transcript_v t
where t.learningid in ('EKP000000708', 'EKP000000523')
group by t.userid, t.learningid;
```